# Android AccountManager no account after restarting application

Tags: android, accountmanager

I followed [this](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) tutorial to set up account for my application. After some struggle I managed to get everything working and my account is created.

```
       if(mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, null)){
            final Account availableAccounts[] = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));
            CL.v("OK " + availableAccounts.length);
        }else{
            CL.v("FAIL");
        }
        mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);
```

After this code I receive that I have 1 account.
Now when I close application and look in account manager there are no accounts associated with my application. And when I start my application

```
final Account availableAccounts[] = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));
```

doesn't return any accounts. I can create it as many times as I want, but it never get's saved. If I click "add new account" in Androids account manager then I see my application and clicking on it takes me to my Activity to create account, and after that everything happens as I described above. One more problem I'm having - there is no label for my application in Account manager, althou I define it in authenticator.xml as android:label="Label"

Answer (score 0):

Every time when I test my application it gets removed, and so does all accounts associated with it.